# Camera rotation at three js not working proper?

Tags: camera, three.js

I am using this function and it is not working properly. Coding is using `three.js`

```
function rotate(){
    camera.rotation.x+=0.1;
}
```

. If I add this at the render function it works just once and not correct meaning that the rotate function event on mouse movement I have, rotates wrong or maybe at an other centre.
What I need is to rotate the camera on the x,y,z axes when the button is clicked.
Any ideas?

Comment: from what i gather there could be a problem in the render function, could you post it?

Comment: function render() {
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    //camera.rotation.x+=10;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    updateLabels();
  } This is the render function.I need the camera.rotation.x+=10; to be inside a function and executed whenever a button is clicked. thx:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined controls. They decide the camera rotation instead of the line you added. You have to set `controls.enabled=false` when you want the camera to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can’t rotate the camera if you later call controls.update(), OrbitControls will overwrite anything what you have applied.
So one simple solution is to not update the controls if you are transforming the camera by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers said the `OrbitControls` overwrite anything
But it looks like three.js now doesn't need to call `controls.update()` as long as you instantiated it `const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);` it will work fine and won't interfere with the camera.

[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcHW02QA5d4)